# Nhibernate 3.2 collection mapping with different types of keys?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

is there any way to map collections in NHibernate 3.2 with different types of keys.

For Example :

one of the table in database has a PK with type of int
another table contains this PK as a string (VARCHAR)

the values are exact-match , so no reason to join them but types are different.

this DB structure does not belong to me, dont offer me to change column type :)

i tried that:

```
public class CustomerMap:EntityMapping<Customer>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the CustomerMap class.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Table("tblcari");

        Id(x => x.CustomerId, 
            m => 
                {
                    m.Column("kod");
                    m.Generator(Generators.Identity);
                });

        Set(x => x.Details, 
            cm =>
            {
                cm.Key(k => 
                    { 
                        k.Column(
                            km => 
                            {
                                km.SqlType("String");
                                km.Name("mkod");
                            }); 
                    });

            },
            m=>m.OneToMany()
            );
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Good question, better even when you add the NHibernate exception.

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be done in fluent-nhibernate because I've done it. Not sure about NH3.2 though. Maybe fluent is you're answer.